# Strange behavior concerning the sample Ionic ToDo app in the docs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm new to the Ionic framework and was trying to follow through the [Ionic ToDo app demonstration](http://ionicframework.com/docs/guide/starting.html). Before starting I want to mention I manually installed the latest ionic release from its GitHub page and included the following in my `index.html`: `ionic.bundle.js`, `angular.min.js`, `angular-animate.min.js`, `angular-resource.min.js`, `angular-sanitize.min.js`, `angular-ui-router.min.js`.  In chapter 5, the author details the controller code to create a new task. I tried adding some extra functionality to the `.createTask()`method defined as

```
$scope.createTask = function(task) {
$scope.tasks.push({
  title: task.title
});
$scope.taskModal.hide();
task.title = "";
};
```

by changing it to

```
$scope.createTask = function(task) {
  if (task.title == "") {
      window.alert("Empty Task!");
      $scope.taskModal.hide();
  }  else {
      $scope.tasks.push({title: task.title})
      $scope.taskModal.hide();
      task.title = "" ;
  };
};
```

Now, if you run this new code with the accompanying view outlined in the tutorial, you will see that the controller calls the empty task alert even if `task.title == ""` fails! Maybe I'm missing something really obvious, but I'm not sure. Furthermore, and the main reason I'm writing this post, if you simply comment out the line `task.title = "";` in the `else` clause and add a task via the live view, it adds two instances of the task created! This is bizarre, or so I thought, as it seems like `$scope.tasks.push({title: task.title});` is being executed twice. So just like any good programmer would do, I tried to make the compiler (in this case interpreter) spill its secrets. I declared a variable in the controller scope, `$scope.i = 0`, to keep track of what was happening. Leaving `//task.title = ""` in its place, I inserted

```
$scope.i += 1;
window.alert($scope.i);
```

right before it. When you run this code, you will notice two things:

1. The controller no longer calls the empty task alert on non-empty tasks.
2. The view is now updated with only one instance of the created task.

So, I'm not really sure what's happening. Maybe it's just some careless error I've overlooked, but any help on this will be really appreciated. Many thanks!

---

**EDIT:**

I tried experimenting further and it seems the whole thing hinges on `window.alert()`. Even if

```
$scope.i += 1;
window.alert($scope.i);
```

is replaced with

```
$window.alert("1");
```

the "solution" still works. Although if you use `window.alert()` or `window.alert("")` the original problem remains.

Comment: `ionic.bundle.js` already contains angular and all the other scripts your mentioning. Try to get rid of the duplicate scripts.

Comment: @LeftyX I tried removing the duplicate files, but the problem remains :/ Also, on [their GitHub](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic), in the *Manual Start* section they mention I will most probably need the angular files in addition to the standard `ionic.js` and `ionic-angular.js` (these two are bundled together in `ionic.bundle.js` I think).

Comment: This is the [content](http://code.ionicframework.com/1.1.0/js/ionic.bundle.js) of the ionic bundle. Check the header.

Comment: @LeftyX Thank you for the upload, I've removed the duplicate files. But still, the symptoms remain...

Comment: It would be useful to create a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/) with your sample so we can investigate.